# best way to convert java.util.HashSet to Clojure set

Tags: clojure, casting, datomic

Datomic queries return `java.util.HashSet` for compatibility purposes. I'd like to use `clojure.set` functions like set difference on query result sets. Currently, I'm converting the result set to Clojure set using `(set datomic_result)`. Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: What's wrong with `(set datomic_result)` approach?

Comment: This suits me right now. The result sets can be potentially big, and I believe there is overhead involved in this.

Comment: Do you need to perform several operations on the result sets, preserving immutability?  If not, and you don't mind modifying the returned `HashSet`s, you are best off using java's `Set` operations (`removeAll` for `difference`, `addAll` for union, etc).  For two 10e6 element `HashSet`s, with 5e6 in the resulting difference, the difference takes 6 seconds to compute using `clojure.set/difference`, and about 1 second using java's `removeAll`.

Comment: @Josh Just put this as an answer. I don't think I need immutability. Do Java's functions work as well with sets of tuples as the Clojure ones, i.e. using `=` on tuple elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend you rely on the fact that the returned value is a `java.util.Set`, which is an implementation detail (according to the Datomic [documentation](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html#find-specifications), the return type is `java.util.Collection`).

You may get better performance by applying your set operation directly to the returned collection instead of coercing to a Set. For instance:

```
;; set difference
(into #{} (remove to-remove) query-result)
;; set intersection
(into #{} (filter to-keep) query-result)
;; set union
(into my-set query-result)
```

The use of [into](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into) lets you leverage both [Transients](https://clojure.org/reference/transients) and [Transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers), which can give you a significant performance boost on large inputs.

Comment: Don't you need a set to make the removal efficient?

Comment: If the righthand set is small it will indeed be faster than a whole scan.

Comment: I'm referring to `O(n^2)` versus `O(n)` performance in using a collection versus a set. But you're right that I should take into account that one of them could be small.

Comment: None of the given examples has O(nm) complexity - only O(n). My previous comment acknowledged that you can get O(m) by using the fact that the returned result is a set.

Comment: Can you enlighten me how it magically knows that an item contained in `query-result` is not inside the collection `to-remove`?

Comment: In the O(m) case: by iterating over `to-remove` and testing for set membership in `query-result`